# What material is it?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials

I'm designing a coordinate measuring machine for my FYP. I need to know what is that black zigzag flexible cover usually made of. Is that leather, rubber or some other material? And how is it fabricated?
[image]

---

It is called a ‘Ball Screw Cover’, they are available in just nylon or fiber coated plastic-
Sometimes, you just need the term for the component to get going down the right path: “Ball Screw Cover”

Comment: Its impossible to tell without knowing more about the machine. Do you know the manufacturer/model or any other info about the machine? Alternatively, you could just ask about what materials would be appropriate for the application and give us some important properties it needs to have.

Answer (score 0):

probably synthetic rubber. the most commonly-used one is ethylene propylene diene monomer, or EPDM.